# Eleventy, LiquidJS, and redefining the Markdown library

Tags: javascript, markdown, liquid, eleventy

I have an Eleventy site where I've [redefined the markdown library](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/markdown/#markdown-options) in order to enable footnotes.

```
let markdownIt = require("markdown-it");
let markdownItFootnote = require("markdown-it-footnote");
let options = {
  html: true,
  breaks: true,
  linkify: false
};

let markdownLib = markdownIt(options).use(markdownItFootnote);
config.setLibrary("md", markdownLib);
```

I'm also trying to implement responsive images via the [eleventy-img plugin](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-img), however it seems by redefining Markdown-It I've lost LiquidJS preprocessing and can't use Liquid-based shortcodes in markdown content (and therefore can't use the async keyword required to get useful responsive images via the plugin's examples). Is there some way to configure Eleventy to get both?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this; I've been using markdown-it plugins and shortcodes  in markdown with no issue. Do you have a minimal repro?